# R Package for publication ready summary tables in descriptive statistics with an export option to LaTeX and other Editors?

Tags: r

1) Descriptive statistics summary tables
I want to build my descriptive statistics summary tables on RStudio with the options to export and use these tables with LaTeX and Editors (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, LibreOffice).

2) Layout options
Moreover I would be great to have many layout options.

3) (Medical) journals 
Furthermore is there the option to convert the tables with "one command" into the design of different (medical) journals?

I know I have a big request, but with my google search I can't solve the problem for many days. The first two are the most important issue for me right now, but I also hope that number three is also possible.

Thank you for your efforts and your helpful advices.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer:

1) & 2) You should take a look at `knitr`, `kableExtra`, `rmarkdown` and `Hmisc` R packages. `officer` can also do the job for MS office export.

3) If your papers and written in LaTeX, you should be able to use the LaTeX class provided by your journal, and not be worried by the final appearance of your tables.
As far as I know (I'm not really a `rmarkdown` or `knitr` user, and not *at all* and Rstudio user), Org-mode for Emacs allows more control on the final output and richer interactions with [LaTeX](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html).

Comment: Thank you. I've already looked at these packages, but I don't make progress.

Are you use the dplyr package for your baseline characteristics and comparison between two groups?